# SQL: how to extract the month from a date time field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to to extract the month from date time fieldA then put the result into fieldB as an integer in the same table IF fieldB is empty.

eg) `1988-02-03 00:00:00.000` I need to extract 02 and put the result into another field only if that field is empty.

I guess this will end up as a stored procedure.

Comment: "I need to extract 02" section is unclear, you;re updating two fields on any condition?

Comment: The answer here is more complete than the proposed duplicate question as it also covers how to update fields and check for empty fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [MONTH()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)

```sql
UPDATE your_table
SET some_column = MONTH(date_column)
WHERE some_column IS NULL
```

Comment: ... assuming that the 02 is actually the month and that the date format isn't `YYYY-DD-MM`

Answer (score 1):

`MONTH(fieldA)` or `DATEPART(M, fieldA)`

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a built-in function called `month()` that will return the month for date and timestamp data types

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET newcolumn = month(columnname)
WHERE newcolumn IS NULL
```

Comment: It will **not** work on  `timestamp` datatypes, since those don't really represent an actual **date** per se ....

Comment: As @marc_s commented, `timestamp` is not date or datetime. The name was such a huge confusion that they are deprecating it: *[The **timestamp** syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)**